# Xcode - request timed out while creating bot and connecting to local server

Tags: xcode, bots

I am trying to create a bot in my Xcode project. I followed below steps:

Launched server at my mac machine.
Turned on Xcode service in server and configured it.

Below are the configurations:

A. Settings

1. Access - Status: Available at myserver.com
2. Access - Permissions: Logged in user can create bots, anyone can view bots
3. Builds - Perform builds using: XCode
4. Builds - Developer Teams: No Teams
5. Devices: No device added

I have also added my bitbucket repository to it.

Then I launched my Xcode project and selected 'create bot...' option. I tried to add new server, it was showing - 'No servers' so entered 'myserver.com' and selected 'Next', it asked me to Add as 'Guest User' or as 'Registered User', I tried both but in each it is giving error - 'Request timed out' :-(

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for future reference:

I had the same problem after an Xcode update (not sure if this is related). A restart of the server (whole Mac, not just the Xcode Server) and deletion and add of the server at the remote computer (Preferences, Accounts, select server, - then + and add it back agin) solved it for me.